# Evaluating a difficult surface integral

Tags: surface-integrals

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HZor.jpg
I need help solving this question,

I know that you can get the parametrization of the ellipsoid but the curl of F seems so difficult to calculate, for part a.  Am I missing something?

Can't apply stokes theorem to part A either because its not a closed surface.

Please help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: added an imagur link of the question.

Comment: You can apply Stoke's theorem in part A. Stoke's theorem says that the integral of $\nabla \times \mathbf F$ over the surface $S$ is equal to the integral of $\mathbf F$ along the boundary of $S$ (which is an ellipse in the $(x,y)$ plane).

Comment: how would you do it?, then i guess im wrong about the second aswell, what would the solution be for both? sorry

Comment: You mean, how would you compute $\oint_C \mathbf F . d \mathbf r$, where $C$ is the ellipse that forms the boundary of $S$? Just parametrise the ellipse using sines and cosines, and compute...

Comment: Ok sorry my brain is fried, makes sense. What about part b?